# Should I fill with 'crowd' or 'crowds' in this context?

Tags: word-usage

> In 1863 the first underground passenger railway in the world opened in London. It ran for just under seven kilometers and allowed people to avoid terrible ____ (crowd) on the roads above as they travelled to and from work.

I am wondering if crowd or crowds should be filled here. And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would say the following:

> **to avoid terrible *crowds* on the roads above**

Why? Because plural ***crowds*** do not require the definite article, whereas singular ***crowd*** does require the definite article. Use *the* when you assume there is just one of something in that place, even if it has not been mentioned before. See: https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/

> **to avoid *the* terrible *crowd* on the roads above**

The definite article is optional with plural *crowds*:

> **to avoid *the* terrible *crowds* on the roads above**

Comment: This is  a good explanation for how to work out the correct answer if this were a question in a test. A more complelling explanation relating to the meaning is that it's difficult to imagine a single crowd seven kilometres long.. one would be more likely to find bunches of people with gaps in between. **crowds**, probably with the definite article, is term that best describes this situation.

Comment: I agree, ***the terrible crowds*** is probably the best option, but the others are OK, too. "Crowd" is a suitably vague term. "Crowds" and "crowd" can mean the same thing.

Comment: @JavaLatte shouldn't it be ... is **the** term that best described ... ? Sorry, but I just want to be clear about it. Thanks.

Comment: @dan, oops: my mistake. There should be definite article where you have indicated.